# CPU usage per application in android

Tags: android

I am new for android programming.How can we get CPU usage per application in android?
your help will be more helpful

Comment: You can display it, by activating the option in the "Developer tools"

Answer (score 69):

Use adb Commands:

```
adb shell top -m 10
```

Comment: i want two things i.e. process name and their usage in percentage only.

Comment: could u please tel what is diff between "adb shell dumpsys cpuinfo" and what info show here using "top"...becasue i am getting two different value of CPU uses here for same app..any idea?

Comment: @CoDe "adb shell dumpsys cpuinfo" doesn't take into consideration multiple cores so MAX is not 100%
This top -m 10 is more user friendly, because you see % based on combined overall CPU usage

Answer (score 22):

Source:
[Technique for indentifying android app CPU usage](http://web.archive.org/web/20131215204905/http://blog.isys-labs.com/tool-for-optimizing-android-app-cpu-usage-and-battery-drain/)

- Linux:

  > adb shell top -m 10 | **grep** *packagename*
- Windows:

  > adb shell top -m 10 | **FINDSTR** *packagename*

Comment: +1 for the grep and the link. this `top` command is refreshing periodically, so one can get CPU usage through various stages of an app. Thanks!

Comment: not working on newest Android devices like Nexus 6P:

See top --help
top: Max 0 arguments

Comment: the Link has been compromised, it leads to a phishing site.

https://google-en.limitedtimeoffers.website/v102102-en-A/index.php?isp=Liberty%20Global%20Operations%20B.V.&lpkey=157d378d35cd737062&uclick=oj2ta1tl#b

Answer (score 12):

Go to `Settings -> Developer Tools -> Show CPU Usage`

Then run the app

EDIT: This has to be done in the app. If you are reading this in 2019, use [CPU Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler)

Comment: isn't there any another way to achieve it?

Comment: There is no `Settings -> Developer Tools -> Show CPU Usage` in Android 8. If you mean `Settings -> Developer Options -> Show Running Services`, this doesn't show CPU usage :(

Comment: Update : Use Android Studio Profiler https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler.html

Comment: where is the "Settings"? I guess you presuppose the usage of Android Studio? That's not self-evident, however. E.g., I don't use it and the question is about android in general. You're answer should mention that it requires Android Studio.

Comment: @pasbi updated answer. These steps were for phone level usage.

Answer (score 11):

two approaches:

- `adb shell "top -n 1"`
- `adb shell dumpsys cpuinfo`

Comment: ok, what if these numbers are crazy different? My top will show me for process A, something like 12% while dumpsys will say 22%...

Comment: @NewGuy This top shows overall %, while cpuinfo doesn't take multiple cores into account. So if dumpsys cpuinfo says 110% and you have 2 core processor, this is 55% overall. So what you usually want is top instead of dumpsys cpuinfo

Answer (score 2):

Using the new [Android Studio 3.0 profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler.html) you can achieve a higher information about the CPU usage and CPU inspection of your APP.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

there are a few ways.

the first one is to open the CPU usage in the Jelly Bean developer options.

the second option is to run the `adb shell top -m 10` function in your windows Android SDK folder or `./adb shell top -m 10` in your Mac/Linux.

Comment: The assumption that the adb executable is in the current directory is unreasonable.  If you are going to assume it is in the search path for windows, you might as well assume it is on the unix variants as well.

Comment: i want two things i.e. process name and their usage in percentage only.

Comment: what can be another way to get it?

Answer (score -1):

This let's you monitor in a more top-esque manner

```
watch -n 0.5 adb shell top -n 1
```

`0.5` is the polling interval

Answer (score -4):

You can use app to access these kinds of information. Such as **Simple System Monitor**, [Simple System Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dp.sysmonitor.app).

Comment: does't show the current % CPU usage per app. Only "total time in foreground" which is useless.