# Measure apps' battery drainage

Tags: android, android-service, battery

There are a lot of questions on here about "My app drains battery! Why?". That is not what I am looking for. I am wondering about how to create an app which can get which apps are draining the most battery.

I know it's possible, because I've seen apps that can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could work it out by CPU usage:

Take a look at this answer:
[CPU usage per application in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042687/cpu-usage-per-application-in-android)

I suspect you would need to continually run a command like this and parse the results into a database, combining previous results to work out a running tally.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough, I meant how can MY app do this.