# Monitoring memory usage by application using adb

Tags: android, memory-management, adb, cpu-usage

I am spawning a couple of apps for my use case and I want to analyze the performance impact of doing so in order to decide between various approaches.
 I use the `adb shell top -m 10` command to monitor the CPU usage constantly.
Is there a similar adb command to recursively display the live system memory usage by application while I perform different operations on my device ?

Comment: Please see this answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19889090/3014115

Comment: The above linked answer is about the CPU usage, not memory.

Comment: android.os.Debug API can help you to monitor memory usage.
It's better than dumpsys meminfo command, more faster than that.